# method client.write() doesn't work on simple server Node.js,

Tags: node.js

Could anybody say why server doesn't display "hello" from client.write("hello") ?

Thank you a lot!

server:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(client) {console.log('new client s')});
server.listen(2345,function(){console.log('opened server on ',2345)});
```

client:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 2345, host:'localhost'},function(){
    console.log('connected to server!');
    client.write("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server is not displaying because you have not handled what to do on recieving data from client :

For server:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 2345;

net.createServer(function(client) {

client.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA ' + client.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    client.write (data);

});

client.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + client.remoteAddress +' '+ client.remotePort);
});

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

for client:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect(2345,'127.0.0.1',function(){
    console.log('connected to server!');
    client.write("hello");
}); 

var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1'; 
var PORT = 2345;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
client.write('Hello');

});
```

Comment: hi rresol, thank you very much for the answer. It solved my problem,